# How can I add scrollable whitespace at the bottom of a QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

When expanding an item at the bottom of a QTreeView, the view does not automatically scroll to show the newly-expanded items. I can fix this by detecting expansion and performing the scroll myself when appropriate.

However, I would instead like to allow the user to scroll the view farther than is currently allowed. Currently, if the tree is too tall to fit in the visible area, the view can be scrolled only until the bottom-most row comes into view.

I believe this should be doable by tricking the QTreeView's size calculation, but even after source diving I don't understand the interaction between QTreeView and its base QAbstractScrollArea well enough to know what to poke, or where to start poking.

If all else fails I may just add some dummy, non-editable rows to my data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add extra white space to the treeview by increasing its vertical scrollbar [maximum](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractslider.html#maximum-prop) value. Smth like this:

```
max = self.treeview.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
self.treeview.verticalScrollBar().setMaximum(max*2)
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: This works well, thanks. The trouble is finding a good place to do it, since the view is constantly adjusting the maximum. The best I have found so far is in scrollbar.rangeChanged, with a guard against infinite recursion.

Comment: I guess another good place would be update it every time you're adding\removing items from your model

Comment: As far as I can tell, that approach is a dead end. Updating the scroll bar in expanded/contracted does not work because the QTreeView updates the scroll bar after the signal is sent. That's why intercepting the lower-level "rangeChanged" is necessary.